# While loop condition not triggered by user input

Tags: python, function, input, control-flow

I am working on a little game to work on my Python skills. As you can see below, I am stuck on getting the program to continue after the user inputs an erroneous value.

One of the things I tried is getting rid of the while loop and wrapping the if statement in a recursive function. However, I am not sure if this is the right way, and it's kind of above my level at the moment. Any thoughts would be very welcome!

```
print("Greetings, weary wanderer.")
print("Welcome to Freyjaberg. Choose your weapon.")
#user able to select from list, needs input and to check which they pick

weapon_choice = (input("You can choose between three weapons to defeat the beast!"
                   " Press 1 for Axe, 2 for Crossbow, 3 for Sword."))

while True:
    weapon_choice <= '4'
    if weapon_choice=='1':
        print("You chose the Axe of Might")
        break
    elif weapon_choice=='2':
        print("You chose the Sacred Crossbow")
        break
    elif weapon_choice=='3':
        print("You chose the Elven Sword")
        break
    else:
        weapon_choice >= '4'
        print("Wanderer, there is no such weapon. Please choose from the ones available.")
        input("You can choose between three weapons to defeat the beast! "
              "Press 1 for Axe, 2 for Crossbow, 3 for Sword.")
```

If I enter 1, 2 or 3, it works fine!

```
Greetings, weary wanderer.
Welcome to Freyjaberg. Choose your weapon.
You can choose between three weapons to defeat the beast! Press 1 for Axe, 2 for Crossbow, 3 for Sword.2
You chose the Sacred Crossbow
Now you must enter the first dungeon. Prepare yourself!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I enter 4 or above, it does show the right error message I expect. So far so good.  Then it prompts me again (as expected). But when I type 1, 2, or 3 now, it doesn't understand and continue. It just keeps telling me it's wrong.

```
Greetings, weary wanderer.
Welcome to Freyjaberg. Choose your weapon.
You can choose between three weapons to defeat the beast! Press 1 for Axe, 2 for Crossbow, 3 for Sword.4
Wanderer, there is no such weapon. Please choose from the ones available.
You can choose between three weapons to defeat the beast! Press 1 for Axe, 2 for Crossbow, 3 for Sword.1
Wanderer, there is no such weapon. Please choose from the ones available.
You can choose between three weapons to defeat the beast! Press 1 for Axe, 2 for Crossbow, 3 for Sword.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take user input in while loop:

```
while True:
    weapon_choice = (input("You can choose between three weapons to defeat the beast!"
               " Press 1 for Axe, 2 for Crossbow, 3 for Sword."))
    try:
        weapon_choice = int(weapon_choice)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Please enter a valid number!")
        continue
    if weapon_choice==1:
        print("You chose the Axe of Might")
        break
    elif weapon_choice==2:
        print("You chose the Sacred Crossbow")
        break
    elif weapon_choice==3:
        print("You chose the Elven Sword")
        break
    else:
        print("Wanderer, there is no such weapon. Please choose from the ones  available.")
```

Comment: Can you explain why it only works when you convert the input to an int?

Comment: @nephele strings comparison is entirely different from numbers comparison in python. When we compare `'a' > 'dfg'` then it will return False as length of 1st string is less than 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

You have to revalue the `weapon_of_choice` variable inside the while loop, as in `weapon_of_choice = input("You can choose between three weapons to defeat the beast! Press 1 for Axe, 2 for Crossbow, 3 for Sword.")`.
The call to `input` only asks for user input, and returns the input value, you have to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain this but I am not sure I understand?